# JavaScript prototype limited to functions?

Tags: javascript, prototype, function, object

o.prototype = {...}
is working only if o is a Function.
Suppose I've the following Code

```
 conf = {
  a: 2,
  b: 4
 };
 conf.prototype = {
  d: 16
 }
```

*conf.a* and *conf.b* is OK and returns proper values. But *conf.d* doesn't return 16 rather it goes undefined. Is there any solution suck that prototype based generalization can also be applied on these type of Objects.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are confusing the `prototype` property that can be used on [Constructor Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_a_Constructor_Function) and the *internal* `[[Prototype]]` property.

All objects have this internal `[[Prototype]]` property, and only the [`new`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.2) operator when you call it with a constructor function is allowed to set it (through the [`[[Construct]]`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2.2) internal operation).

If you want to have prototypal inheritance with object instances (without using constructors), the Crockford's [`Object.create`](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) technique is what you want (that method is now part of the recently approved ECMAScript 5th Edition):

```
// Check if native implementation available
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
  Object.create = function (o) {
    function F() {}  // empty constructor
    F.prototype = o; // set base object as prototype
    return new F();  // return empty object with right [[Prototype]]
  };
}

var confProto = {
  d: 16
};
var conf = Object.create(confProto);
conf.a = 2;
conf.b = 4;
```

In the above code `conf` will have its three members, but only `a` and `b` will exists physically on it:

```
conf.hasOwnProperty('a'); // true 
conf.hasOwnProperty('b'); // true
conf.hasOwnProperty('d'); // false
```

Because `d` exists on the conf `[[Prototype]]` (`confProto`).

The [property accessors](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.1), `.` and `[]` are responsible to resolve the properties looking up if necessary in the prototype chain (through the [`[[Get]]`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8.6.2.1) internal method).

Comment: Could the downvoter please leave a comment? I'm always looking to improve my answers :)

Answer (score 6):

There are actually two different kind of "prototype" in JavaScript:

1. One is the "hidden" link every object has (let's use `[[Prototype]]` to represent this hidden link). object literals by default have their hidden links pointing to `Object.prototype`, function objects have their hidden link pointing to `Function.prototype`, and arrays have theirs pointing to `Array.prototype`. These ***hidden prototype links*** are not related to properties with name "prototype". You can't change these hidden links by adding or modifying `o.prototype`.
2. Another one is that all function objects automatically have a special property named "`prototype`". This is mainly for the usage of constructor invocation pattern.

`[[Prototype]]` is used for searching properties (like the parent in classical hierarchy), whenever a property cannot be found in an object, its `[[Prototype]]` is searched instead. One usage scenario: say you'd like to add a property to all objects, you could simply add it to `Object.prototype` which would automatically apply to all objects since all objects somehow have `Object.prototype` as their `[[Prototype]]` chain root.

Lets get back to function objects' "`prototype`" property. It is only useful when used with operator `new`. Take the following code snippet as an example:

```
function F() {} // function declaration
// F now has a property named "prototype"

var f = new F(); // use "new" operator to create a new function object based on F
```

What `new F()` does above is to first create a new function object, set the `[[Prototype]]` (hidden link) of this newly created function object to be `F.prototype`, and then return the new function object. This is probably what you already understand that works for function objects.

Remember that I said we can't change objects's `[[Prototype]]`? Well, at least not directly. Crockford's `Object.create` function does just that, by utilizing the fact that operator `new` could help set `[[Prototype]]` for us. So by using `Object.create`, you get to deliberately indicate where your new object's hidden link should point to. (somewhat feel like indicating who is your parent class)

In your example, `conf` is an object literal and `conf.prototype` isn't really useful. Here's another version utilizing classical style:

```
function ConfBase() {}
ConfBase.prototype.d = 16;
var conf = new ConfBase();
conf.a = 2;
conf.b = 4;

document.writeln(conf.a);
document.writeln(conf.b);
document.writeln(conf.d);
```

Compared to the answer of @CMS, I do prefer using `Object.create`. But essentially the 2 styles are using the same underlying mechanism, just that `Object.create` helps tidy it up.