# Inheriting objects

Tags: javascript, class, scope, prototypal-inheritance

I have read that Javascript's inheritance is prototypal.What does it mean?How can an object defined by the programer inherit the properties of a predefined object such as window ?
For example I need the function eval()  in my own class . How can it be achieved?

Comment: Why would you inherit eval? Using eval in code is 99.99% of the time the wrong thing to do.

Comment: For what purpose you need to *inherit* `eval`? The ECMAScript 5th Edition Specification made semantic changes to the behavior of `eval` when it's used in an indirect way -like in the way I think you are willing to use it, e.g. `myObj.eval`-, `eval` has no access to the caller's variable/lexical environment, it uses the global environment. Only direct `eval` calls have access to the caller lexical environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want exactly echieve to?
Here is the simplest way (not the best) of prototype inheritance:

```
var obj1=new Object1Constructor();
var obj2=new Object2Constructor();

obj2.prototype=obj1;
```

It means that `obj1` inherits all properties of `obj2`

I've forgot the main thing: eval==evil;

UPDATE:
I've made mistakes in the code above. That is not inheritance. Here is updated code:

```
var Object1Constructor=function(){ // one object constuctor
    //properties definition goes here
}

var Object2Constructor=function(){ // another object constuctor
    //properties definition goes here
}

Object2Constructor.prototype=new Object1Constructor();

var obj=new Object2Constructor();
```

And that is inharitance. Now `obj` has properties defined in `Object2Constructor` and `Object1Constructor` - parent 'class'. 
See CMS's comment below. He is totally right.

Comment: The `prototype` property is only relevant to function objects -when used as Constructors-, you can't set the `[[Prototype]]` internal property of `obj2` like that, you're just creating a property named `"prototype"` on it (nothing about inheritance). The only way to *change* an already initialized object `[[Prototype]]` is through the non-standard and deprecated `__proto__` property. More info about `prototype` vs `[[Prototype]]`: [JavaScript prototype limited to functions ??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111288/javascript-prototype-limited-to-functions/2111353)

Comment: Yes. You are right. Please, look on updated code. Is it correct now?

Comment: yes, it looks good now, I would just set the `constructor` property of `Object2Constructor.prototype` back to `Object2Constructor` after replacing it, otherwise `obj.constructor` in your example, will refer to `Object1Constructor` (also, I would add semicolons also at the end of the function expressions -or use function definitions instead- but this isn't completely required).

Answer (score 3):

Setting aside the question of whether you *should* inherit from `window`, here's a simple example that demonstrates *how* to do it:

```
function Test() {
    // constructor code
}

Test.prototype = window;

var t = new Test();
t.eval();
```

When invoked using the `new` operator, the `Test` function creates a new instance of `Test` whose prototype is linked to the `window` object. A function's prototype can be any object.

Answer (score 1):

Protip: Don't use `new` for declaring objects. Object.create is the proper way to create JavaScript objects. It's supported in all modern browsers. For other browsers, a nice shim is at the bottom of this article:

http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

One problem with constructors that use 'new' is that if people accidentally call it like a regular function, it will make modifications on the global variable (i.e. window if in the browser) using the variable `this`, so `this` should only be reserved for prototype functions, and I prefer to use `that` instead of `this`

I personally use a style that supports `new obj()`, `obj()`, and `obj.init()`, which may be one extra function pointer, but I think it adds semantic meaning

```
function obj(){
    var that = Object.create(obj.prototype)
    //any constructor logic goes here
    return that
}
obj.prototype = Object.create(Superclass.prototype)

obj.init = obj //completely optional

//other function declarations

obj.prototype.someFunction = function(){
    //logic for someFunction
}
```

Comment: Is create() a part of standard Javascript Library? Or a part of frameworks like this?http://www.prototypejs.org/api/class/create

Comment: @user822982, `Object.create` is part of the ECMAScript 5th Edition Specification, but it's [not completely emulable on ECMAScript 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830800/object-defineproperty-in-es5/3844768#3844768) implementations, the Crockford's `Object.create` shim cannot handle the second argument, to define properties with descriptors and it cannot create objects that inherit from `null`.