# confusion about javascript exercise

Tags: javascript, oop

I just got Javascript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford and I'm having some difficulty understanding one of his examples regarding prototypes. The code in the book reads as follows:

```
if (typeof Object.create !== "function") {
    Object.create = function(o) {
        var F = function () {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F;
    };
}
```

I'm assuming that this code is used to target a function's prototype. But why use such a complex approach? Why not just use `variable`.prototype? Crockford is the leading expert on Javascript so I'm sure there is a good reason for using this model. Can anyone help me understand it better? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ECMAScript 3, the `new` operator was the only standard way to set the `[[Prototype]]` *internal property* of an object, in this case, Crockford is just using a *temporary constructor function* `F` for that purpose.

The `o` argument of that method, is set as the `prototype` property of the temporary constructor, and by invoking `new F();` it builds a new empty object that inherits from `F.prototype` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750880/javascript-how-does-new-work-internally) for more details about how `new` works).

For example:

```
var a = { a: 1 };
var b = Object.create(a); // b inherits from a
b.a; // 1
```

In the above example, we can say that the `b`'s internal `[[Prototype]]` property points to `a`.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(b) === a; // true
```

In other words, `b` inherits from `a`.

With the same example, we could use an empty constructor, e.g.:

```
 function F(){}
 F.prototype = a;

 var b = new F(); // b again inherits from a (F.prototype)
```

Remember also that the `prototype` property of functions is different than the `[[Prototype]]` property that all objects have, the `prototype` property of functions is used when they are called with the new operator, to build a new object that inherits from that property.

Also, be aware that now, the ECMAScript 5 Standard is being implemented, and this shim, doesn't conform 100% with the spec, in fact, there are some features of the standard `Object.create` method [that cannot be emulated on ES3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830800/object-defineproperty-in-es5/3844768#3844768).

See also:

- [JavaScript prototype limited to functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111288/javascript-prototype-limited-to-functions)

Comment: @CMS--but in this case, `Object.create` is set to an empty function. So there is no inheritance here... right? Also, since `Object.create` is a method of the `Object` constructor, setting it equal to an empty function would be `null` correct?

Comment: @codeninja, I don't get why you say `Object.create` is *set* to an *empty* function, maybe due the last line (`return new F;`)??? That last line just returns a new object invoking the `F` constructor (an object that inherits from `F.prototype`), it might look unfamiliar since the parentheses are missing at the end, but they are optional when you use the `new` operator (`new F();` is equivalent to `new F;`)...

Comment: @CMS--The code reads `Object.create = var F` which is set `=` to `function() {}`. doesn't this mean it is in some sense set to an empty function?

Comment: @codeninja, no, the empty function is just *used inside* the parent function (the one that has the `o` parameter), `Object.create` in this example is set to a function that accepts an argument (`o`), builds a temporal function inside its scope (the empty one), and returns a new object that inherits from the `o` argument provided.

Answer (score 3):

```
var bar = Object.create(foo)
```

vs.

```
var bar = new Object()
```

the first `bar` has `foo` as its prototype; the second has `Object` as its prototype.

Comment: Typo: "the second has `Object` as its prototype" should be "the second has `Object.prototype` as its prototype ..." (`Object` is just a constructor function)

Comment: @Claudiu--in this case `Object.create` is set to `function()`, it does not assign a prototype to any variable.

Answer (score 1):

This code is for older JavaScript implementations that do not support `Object.create`, which is specified in the ECMAScript 5 standard released in November 2009.

Many people say the preferred way to create an object is to specify a prototype for it at the time of creation.  This can be called `differential inheritance` or `prototypal inheritance`.  In fact, that is what `Object.create` does:

```
var protoCircle = {x: 0, y: 0, radius: 1, color:"black"};
var myCircle = Object.create(protoCircle);
myCircle.x = 3;
myCircle.color = "green";
```

This make a green circle of radius 1 centered at (3,0).

The reason the code is so complex that before `Object.create` was added to JavaScript, the *only way to set an object's prototype was to create it with the `new` operator*.  Objects created with `new` got, as their prototype, the value of the constructor's `prototype` property.  It's definitely confusing, but the `prototype` property is NOT the prototype of an object.  Given a function object `f`, `f.prototype` is the object that will be assigned as the prototype of all objects constructed through `new f()`.  An object's real prototype is called `[[prototype]]` or `__proto__` but you cannot access these in standard ECMAScript. Confusing, eh?

As a side note. the ES5 specification has a more enhanced `Object.prototype` specification than the one Crockford defined.  It takes a second object for configuring properties of the object being defined.

Answer (score 0):

This create method will instantiate a new object given the passed object as the prototype.