# Prototypes and object creation

Tags: javascript, inheritance, object, prototype-programming

Lately I'm trying to get the technical aspects of the prototype chain. Now I have a few questions about object instantiation.

Consider the following code:

```
var Foo = function(s) {
  this._bar = s;
};

var fooInst = new Foo('test');
```

Now when I examine the created object, then:

```
Foo.prototype === Function.prototype; // true

fooInst.prototype === ?
fooInst.prototype.prototype === Object.prototype; // true
```

I'm wondering, what `fooInst.prototype` exactly is. In Chromes inspector it seems to be some kind of `Foo` with an `constructor` property. But all sources I read about prototypes state that `fooInst.prototype === Foo.prototype` should be true.

So my question: how exactly does JS handle the prototype chain. What exactly happens when I call `new Foo`.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

So I found, that (in Chrome) `Object.getPrototypeOf(fooInst) === Foo.prototype;` is `true`, but `Object.getPrototypeOf(fooInst) === Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo)` is `false`. Why that?

Comment: `Foo` is a function, `fooInst` is a `Foo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm wondering, what fooInst.prototype exactly is.

It is `undefined`.

```
fooInst.prototype === undefined; // true
```

Only functions have an automatic `.prototype` property. Objects do not.

If you create an object using a constructor, like:

```
var fooInst = new Foo('test');
```

...then `fooInst` will have an internal reference to `Foo.prototype`, but there's no *standard* property to get `Foo.prototype` from `fooInst`.

---

That said, there is a *non-standard* property that is supported in *some* JavaScript environments for referencing the prototype object.

```
fooInst.__proto__ === Foo.prototype; // true (if __proto__ supported)
```

Also, there is a *method* provided by *ECMAScript 5* that can be used.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf( fooInst ) === Foo.prototype;  // true
```

---

That internal reference from an object to its prototype object can be just the first in a chain of such references.

The prototype object likely has its own prototype object that is referenced. *(In basic cases, this will be `Object.prototype`, or with longer chains, `Object.prototype` may be further down the chain.)*

`Object.prototype` itself references `null` as its prototype. This ends the chain.

You should note that the internal reference from an object to its prototype object does not change if you change the `.prototype` object of the constructor function. It is a reference that exists for the life of the object.

```
var Foo = function(s) {
  this._bar = s;
};

var fooInst = new Foo('test');

Object.getPrototypeOf( fooInst ) === Foo.prototype;  // true

// Change the prototype object of Foo
Foo.prototype = { some:'object' };

Object.getPrototypeOf( fooInst ) === Foo.prototype;  // false
```

Comment: But I assume, that any object has a prototype object? And `Object.getPrototypeOf(fooInst)` gives `Foo.prototype`.

Comment: @mAu: Yes, see my update. I reference the standard `.getPrototypeOf()` method, and the non-standard `.__proto__` property. If you create an object using `Object.create()`, you can actually set the prototype to `null` instead of an Object. `var o = Object.create( null );`

Answer (score 2):

Your first assumption:

```
Foo.prototype === Function.prototype;
```

Is not right, I think you are mixing up the concept of the `[[Prototype]]` internal property that all objects have, and makes the "link" of the prototype chain, and the `prototype` property that function objects have.

The above comparison will produce `false` because the value of the `Foo.prototype` property is a new object, created at the time you created the `Foo` function.

This object is initialized whenever you create a function object, it inherits from `Object.prototype` and it has a property, named `constructor` that points back to the function (`Foo.prototype.constructor === Foo`), and it's used when you call your function as a constructor.

Now, if we talk about the `[[Prototype]]` internal property, you are right, the `[[Prototype]]` of your `Foo` function is `Function.prototype` in other words, `Foo` inherits from `Function.prototype`, e.g.:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo) === Function.prototype; // true
Foo instanceof Function; // true
Foo.__proto__ === Function.prototype; // true
```

About `fooInst` this object was created in a *new expression*, when you used your `Foo` function as a constructor, this new object is produced, and it inherits from `Foo.prototype`, (its internal `[[Prototype]]` property points to `Foo.prototype`).

It doesn't have a `prototype` property, since this property is only meaningful for function objects.

See also:

- [JavaScript prototype limited to functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111288/javascript-prototype-limited-to-functions)
- [How does 'new' work internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750880/javascript-how-does-new-work-internally/)

Comment: Thanks to you too, you're right, I mixed up the two `prototype` and `[[Prototype]]`s.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the explanations and diagrams in [JavaScript. The Core](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/) useful here.

All objects have a prototype chain. As such, `fooInst` has a prototype chain, at the head of which is `Foo.prototype`. When you called `new Foo`, an Object was created, `Foo.prototype` was set as its prototype chain and the constructor function was called in the context of the new Object.

Some browsers expose this as a *non-standard* `__proto__` property, such that:

```
fooInst.__proto__ === Foo.prototype
```